# Regular expression for everything after .jsp (not including)

Tags: regex

I'm new to regex and am having issues trying to write this specific regular expression.

I need to select everything *after* .jsp (not including)

For example:

/common/login/signup.jsp?email=fdsfds[redacted email]o.com&authcode=sfdfsdfsd

Match: ?email=fdsfds[redacted email]o.com&authcode=sfdfsdfsd

Can an expert please help?

Comment: What language/regex tool are you using here?

Comment: There are tons of resources for how to extract the query string from a URL.  Have you done any research into this?

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple regex works now!

```
(?<=\jsp).*
```